# Get HTTP status code from a response coming as empty with $http service

Tags: angularjs, http

I'm having trouble getting the HTTP status code from a empty response that is empty. status code is required to show the corresponding message that happened.

[image: success data is empty for empty response]
[image]

I Tried everything but couldn't get the http status code from the response. Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this server is broken. I don't think there's a circumstance where `POST` can result in a `304 Not Modified` response.

Usually `304 Not Modified` is in response to a GET or HEAD request, when `If-Match` or `If-Modified-Since` is used.

However, if those headers are used for other HTTP requests (such as POST), the correct response is `412 Precondition Failed`.

You usually never see a `304`, because when it's used correctly (with GET), the browser will still not expose the 304, but instead it will give you a `200` and a response that's served directly from cache.

So in short, my best guess is that you can't, because your server doesn't conform with HTTP all assumptions are kind of out of the window.

Answer (score 0):

A Promise that will be resolved (request success) or rejected (request failure) with a response object.

The response object has these properties:

**data** – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.

**status** – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.

**headers** – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.

**config** – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.

**statusText** – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

**xhrStatus** – {string} – Status of the XMLHttpRequest (complete, error, timeout or abort).

So in your case you can add second parameter as status to get status code